# Express.js send response before end of execution

Tags: node.js, express

In a Express application I would like to do something like this:

```
app.get('/some/route', someMiddleWare(), function(req, res){
    var status = undefined;
    if( /*someCondition*/ ) status = 200;
    else status = 403

    res.status(status).send('');

    // do something else
})
```

In the first part I do something that is needed in order to decode what response to give, in the second (after `send()`) I do something additional that needs to be done in the same execution (i.e. not asynchronously) but does not really concern the user. 
The question is: can I be sure that after `send()` returns the response is already on its way back to the user? Or is it sent only after the execution of my handler function?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is: can I be sure that after `send()` returns the response
>   is already on its way back to the user? Or is it sent only after the
>   execution of my handler function?

Yes, you can be sure the data is on its way.  At the point you call `res.send()`, the data has been written to the underlying TCP infrastructure and it is then up to the TCP stack to send it.  Due to TCP Nagle algorithm, there might be a short delay before the data is sent, but it will not be waiting for anything in your Express application.  The data will be sent as soon as the TCP stack decides to send it.

It won't matter whether you are doing something else in the request handler after you send the response or not.

If you want to follow the actual source code for this, you first look at [`res.send(data)` in express](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L100) and that ultimately ends up calling [`res.end(data)` in the http module](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L533).  And, by looking at the http module, you can see that it is writing the data to the TCP implementation synchronously when it is called.  There are no magic delays waiting for other things to happen in Express.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You're code will execute in the function even after you send the data through `res.send()`.

However, after you use `res.send()` you will no longer be able to send any other data with that same response to that request.